# Should the toml file be added to version control for a python poetry managed project?

Tags: python, git, version-control, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

Should the `pyproject.toml` file be added to version control for a python poetry managed project? The poetry documentation mentions adding the lock file, however I was unable to find guidance on the `pyproject.toml` file.

https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#commit-your-poetrylock-file-to-version-control

Comment: Poetry docs doesn't mention it because poetry doesn't handle the file, it merely use it if exists. The rest is up to you. It's advised to commit the file but not strictly required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should.

The `pyproject.toml` is the heart of your Poetry based project. It contains the metadata like name and version and the definitions of the direct dependencies.

Without this file it is impossible to install the project and its dependencies. Furthermore you cannot build and publish the package.

The lock file only does not include enough information to install the project (https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1301).